# Remove string from dataframe index values

Tags: numpy

I want to remove strings from my index values:

```
df.index.get_values().str.replace("and over", "").astype(int)
```

Doing this returns the following error:

```
AttributeError: 'numpy.ndarray' object has no attribute 'str'
```

I've tried to find a similar function used by numpy to achieve this but I can't seem to find any. Here are my index values:

```
['0' '1' '2' '3' '4' '5' '6' '7' '8' '9' '10' '11' '12' '13' '14' '15'
 '16' '17' '18' '19' '20' '21' '22' '23' '24' '25' '26' '27' '28' '29'
 '30' '31' '32' '33' '34' '35' '36' '37' '38' '39' '40' '41' '42' '43'
 '44' '45' '46' '47' '48' '49' '50' '51' '52' '53' '54' '55' '56' '57'
 '58' '59' '60' '61' '62' '63' '64' '65' '66' '67' '68' '69' '70' '71'
 '72' '73' '74' '75' '76' '77' '78' '79' '80' '81' '82' '83' '84' '85'
 '86' '87' '88' '89' '90 and over' 'All ages']
```

Comment: Move the method `get_values` after the `replace` such as `df.index.str.replace("and over", "").get_values()` should not throw an error. But the `astype` might not work as you also have 'All ages' that can't be change to `int`

Comment: @Ben.T If the All ages string was replaced to be an empty string would it be possible to loop through the index changing each value to an integer?

Comment: Don't think so, you can try to replace by `-1` and it should work. If you explain more why you want to change the type and the final application, it may bring other solution

Comment: @Ben.T The dataframe contains the population of an area broken down by age. Using the data, I am creating a line graph with matplotlib to show how the population (y axis) changes for the area by age (x axis). Because there are so many index values, they overlap on the x axis. To solve this I thought it may help if the index was recognised by the file as numerical rather than as strings, which would remove the overlap automatically. I'll also be using the data to produce other graphs and thus wanted the problem to be solved with one solution.

Answer (score 0):

Something like the following code should work. But first, you would have to delete the 'All ages' entry.

```
arr = np.array([x.replace(' and over', '') for x in arr]).astype(int)
```